# type argument ‘nw_proxy_config_t‘ is neither an Objective-C object nor a block type

Tags: ios, flutter, xcode, cocoapods, ios17

Cannot build on latest Xcode 15 Stable, iOS 17 stable

Related to
https://github.com/pichillilorenzo/flutter_inappwebview/issues/1735

```
flutter run
```

```
Could not build the precompiled application for the device.
Error (Xcode): type argument 'nw_proxy_config_t' (aka 'struct nw_proxy_config *') is neither an Objective-C object nor a block type
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS17.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/WebKit.framework/Headers/WKWebsiteDataStore.h:119:46

Parse Issue (Xcode): Could not build module 'WebKit'
/build/ios/Debug-iphoneos/flutter_inappwebview/flutter_inappwebview.framework/Headers/flutter_inappwebview-Swift.h:285:8


Error launching application on iPhone
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Fix: Upgrade flutter from master branch, delete podfile.lock and rerun pod install

Temporal fix:

**Workaround** 1 from GitHub:

Use sudo and yor favorite text editor:

```
open /Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS17.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/WebKit.framework/Headers/WKWebsiteDataStore.h,
```

change the `__IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED` from 170000 to 180000

**Workaround 2**:

```
post_integrate do |installer|
  compiler_flags_key = 'COMPILER_FLAGS'
  project_path = 'Pods/Pods.xcodeproj'

  project = Xcodeproj::Project.open(project_path)
  project.targets.each do |target|
    target.build_phases.each do |build_phase|
      if build_phase.is_a?(Xcodeproj::Project::Object::PBXSourcesBuildPhase)
        build_phase.files.each do |file|
          if !file.settings.nil? && file.settings.key?(compiler_flags_key)
            compiler_flags = file.settings[compiler_flags_key]
            file.settings[compiler_flags_key] = compiler_flags.gsub(/-DOS_OBJECT_USE_OBJC=0\s*/, '')
          end
        end
      end
    end
  end
  project.save()
end
```

**Workaround 3** update

CocoaPods

```
gem install cocoapods
```

and run :

```
flutter clean 

flutter upgrade

cd ios && pod repo update

flutter run
```

**Extra :**

```
Update flutter_inappwebview to latest version ^5.8.0
```

And the project must build without problems

Comment: workaround 2 worked

Comment: Spot on! Workaround worked for me! (for macOS)

Comment: Workaround 2 on ios/Podfile worked here with flutter 2.10.5 and XCode 15.0.1. Thanks!

Answer (score 15):

Update *flutter_inappwebview* to 5.8.0 works for me.

Comment: The workaround worked for me!

Comment: Worked for me as well! Very easy and works like a charm.