# error: type argument 'nw_proxy_config_t' (aka 'struct nw_proxy_config *') is neither an Objective-C object nor a block type (KMM)

Tags: android, xcode, kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform

So the thing is i have multiplatform project setup in which i am implementing ios dependency by cocoapod dependency manger by adding :

```
pod("AEPCore"){

        version = "4.1.0"
    }

    pod("AEPLifecycle"){
        version = "4.1.0"
    }
```

But the problem is whenever i build the project i am getting this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS17.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/WebKit.framework/Headers/WKWebsiteDataStore.h:120:47: error: type argument 'nw_proxy_config_t' (aka 'struct nw_proxy_config *') is neither an Objective-C object nor a block type
```

which doesn't allow to make klib after that.

had some solution from flutter user but not working on multiplatform , because can't edit WKWebsiteDataStore.h file with root access too.

Suggested Workarounds:
[type argument ‘nw_proxy_config_t‘ is neither an Objective-C object nor a block type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77189557/type-argument-nw-proxy-config-t-is-neither-an-objective-c-object-nor-a-block-t)